# Solution of this error "build_e78zp1j4o0zl1p0yedk066716$_run_closure1@16415a4c " in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle

The error is not allowing the app to run and its even after changing the value of the compileSdkVersion and buildToolVersion. 
It is not allowing the code to connect with the android function present in the app gradle.

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mridul.smartbin"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })

  //noinspection GradleCompatible
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
  //noinspection GradleCompatible
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try cordova clean android and the build again.

Comment: remove this option " buildToolsVersion "26.0.3""